# How to set prompt value on setSelection() on Spinner in Android

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I am making for spinner controls with fragment of multiple and first fragment show spinner properly and after then second fragment call then i set on default spinner not set plz help me, thanks in advance

```
String[] strArraySpinner = { "Existing Customer ?", "New Customer ?" };
    mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(strArraySpinner[0])) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, "Item= " + mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            } else if (mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(strArraySpinner[1])) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, "Item= " + mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }  
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
```

And second fragment calls when i m selection method on spinner call and this is not working,

```
mSpinner.setSelection();  // here i m set on default spinner with prompt
```

Comment: @henrywright, don't just fix *one* problem in your edits.  This question contains numerous spelling and grammar issues that you could also have corrected.  Watch out, if you get too many suggested edits rejected, you will be *blocked* from editing.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Charles - I will check the whole document in far more detail from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found for my self solution as `mSpinner.setSelection();` method remove and set again spinner of adapter calling,

```
mSpinner.setAdapter(new SpinnerBaseAdapter(mContext, strArraySpinner);
```

This is working fine and change for each an every items inside of dropdown and get the results.