# Android resetting spinner to prompt text

Tags: android, spinner, prompt

Is it possible to reset the spinner to the prompt text, after a user makes a selection?

I am aware of the following

```
spinnerName.setSelection(index);
```

But the prompt text is not stored in the string-array supplied to the Spinner.

In my xml file I have the following prompt text hardcoded in the Spinner view:

```
android:prompt="@string/Prompt Text"
```

How am I able to set this pragmatically?

Answer (score 0):

```
 spinnerName.setAdapter(new BaseAdapterClass(getContext(), R.arraystring);
```

answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18029559/2746921